# How to create a Application that phone can use to send Radio Frequency Wave?

Tags: android, setuptools, tracking, diagram

I need a mobile application for Android phone making it send a Radio Frequency Wave and create a Device that can receiver the wave and show the location of the phone.

I try to make a application with Android Studio but the application I make not working. And the Device I looking for tools I can use to create it.

Comment: The mobile radio nor the Wifi/Bluetooth radio are software programmable (SDR-alike), so what you what to do is not possible. Only if you have phones with Ultra-wideband (UWB) support (requires special hardware) you could try that.